# Is calling a instance method during initialization poor form?

Tags: ruby, class

I was thinking of ways to improve the following class and it occurred to me: **Is it poor form to call a instance method during initialization?**

Originally I had the method set_last_updated_on as the first line in the "run" method, and it's likely i'll keep it there, but the question remains as stated above.

```
class FinancialUpdateService
  def initialize(stock)
    @stock = stock
    set_last_updated_on
  end

  def run
    fetch_latest_financial_data
    remove_duplicate_data
    store_latest_financial_data  
  end

  private

  def set_last_updated_on
    @last_updated_on = @stock.financials.first.date.to_date
  end

  def fetch_latest_financial_data
    @latest_financial_data = StockDataApi.new(@stock.symbol, {start_date: @last_updated_on, end_date: Date.today-1}).financial_history
  end

  def remove_duplicate_data
    @latest_financial_data.delete_if { |data| data[:date].to_date <= @last_updated_on}
  end

  def store_latest_financial_data
    @latest_financial_data.each do |d| 
      @stock.financials.create(adj_close: d.fetch(:adj_close), close: d.fetch(:close),
      date: d.fetch(:date).to_time, high: d.fetch(:high), low: d.fetch(:low), open: d.fetch(:open),
      volume: d.fetch(:volume))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: initialize initializes the object so it is quite normal to call private methods to set state. However I would endever to get initializer simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a class method, that's an instance method.

And no, it's not poor form. It's completely normal and desirable to call a method inside `initialize`.

Comment: Oh man, rookie mistake. I was focused on the question and called it a class method when it's obviously an instance method. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

The problems start when you call methods that a subclass overrides.

Since the instance isn't fully instantiated yet, and an overridden method might assume a fully-instantiated instance, unusual behavior may surface, e.g., a property might not be initialized.